# Cmake complains about Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY)

Tags: curl, cmake, curlpp

I am building `curl` and `curlpp` from source in my `CMakeLists.txt` using `FetchContent` to use in an executable later in my `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(myproject VERSION 1.0.0)

include(FetchContent)
include(CMakePrintHelpers)

cmake_print_variables(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS)

if (WIN32)
    set(CMAKE_USE_SCHANNEL ON)
endif()

# --- CURL
FetchContent_Declare(curl
        URL                    https://github.com/curl/curl/releases/download/curl-7_75_0/curl-7.75.0.tar.xz
        URL_HASH               SHA256=fe0c49d8468249000bda75bcfdf9e30ff7e9a86d35f1a21f428d79c389d55675 # the file hash for curl-7.75.0.tar.xz
        USES_TERMINAL_DOWNLOAD TRUE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(curl)

add_library(curl_int INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(curl_int INTERFACE libcurl)
target_include_directories(curl_int INTERFACE ${curl_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${curl_BINARY_DIR}/include/curl)
add_library(CURL::mylibcurl ALIAS curl_int)
set(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR
        ${curl_SOURCE_DIR}/include
        )


# --- CURL C++
FetchContent_Declare(curlpp
        GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp.git
        )
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(curlpp) # ----> Error occurs here
cmake_print_variables(curlpp_SOURCE_DIR curlpp_BINARY_DIR)
add_library(curlpp_int INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(curlpp_int INTERFACE libcurlpp CURL::mylibcurl)
target_include_directories(curlpp_int INTERFACE ${curlpp_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${curlpp_BINARY_DIR}/include/curl)
add_library(CURLPP::mylibcurlpp ALIAS curlpp_int)
set(CURLPP_INCLUDE_DIR
        ${curlpp_SOURCE_DIR}/include
        )
set(CURLPP_LIB_DIR
        ${curlpp_BINARY_DIR})

cmake_print_variables(CURLPP_LIB_DIR)
cmake_print_variables(CURLPP::mylibcurlpp)

# The rest of CMakeLists.txt is omitted
```

However, during cmake build, when it executes `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(curlpp)`, I get a complaint about

```
Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY)
```

I am linking `curlpp` with `curl` by `target_link_libraries(curlpp_int INTERFACE libcurlpp CURL::mylibcurl)` and was expecting it to be able to find it.

How could I solve this?

Comment: You have a bunch of interface libraries but nothing that compiles to a binary. Is your error message a CMake error or a compiler error? What line does it correspond to?

Answer (score 1):

In the CMake of curlpp, the CURL library is required and fetched if not available:

```
71 message(STATUS "Looking for CURL")
72 find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
73
.  if(CURL_FOUND)
.    message(STATUS "Found CURL version: ${CURL_VERSION_STRING}")
.    message(STATUS "Using CURL include dir(s): ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
.    message(STATUS "Using CURL lib(s): ${CURL_LIBRARIES}")
.  else()
.    message(STATUS "Fetching CURL")
.    include(FetchContent)
.    FetchContent_Declare(CURL GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/curl/curl.git)
.    FetchContent_MakeAvailable(CURL)
.  endif()
```

- https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L72

I could think of two problems here, but also more information might be helpful, for example, if your error is thrown in line 72 or above that.

- One option would be, that you build CURL into a directory that then is not found in the curlpp find_package call.
- Another option would be that your versions are not compatible, looking at the code from curlpp they by default would download the master repo of curl.